# PHP Regex replace text between brackets AND brackets

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have the following string:

```
Welcome [firstname] [lastname]
```

I am trying to use `preg_replace()` so that [firstname] is replaced with **Marcello** and [lastname] with **Silvestri**.

I have only been able to find the way to get the text inside the brackets, but I want to replace the brackets themselves.

```
$string = "Welcome [firstname] [lastname]";

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '\[firstname\]';
$patterns[1] = '\[lastname\]';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'Marcello';
$replacements[1] = 'Silvestri';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $array, $string]);
```

I also tried with `\[(.*?)\]` trying to replace everything regardless of the square brackets content, but I get something like `[Marcello]`, while I just want `Marcello`.

How can I replace the content including the square brackets?

Comment: the pattern needs to be pre and appended with delimiters. You could use a `/`, like `'/\[firstname\]/'`

Comment: Use error reporting in the future. This would have thrown: `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` after the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' on line 12` was fixed. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't **really** need regex for this, so here's a simple `str_replace` example.

```
$string = "Welcome [firstname] [lastname]";

$find = [
    '[firstname]','[lastname]'
];
$replace = [
    'Marcellus','Wallace'
];

$modified = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);

print $modified;
```

Will output

```
Welcome Marcellus Wallace
```

Comment: I feel really stupid in this moment. A quick question: why would  you suggest this method over regex (if this can be done with regex too)?

Comment: I guess I would go for `str_replace` because this isn't a complex string replacement where you would benefit from a regular expression match, in fact it's a straight through simple string replace.

Comment: Also, it looks like `preg_replace` is **considerably** slower than `str_replace` _who'd a thunk it_ :) here some random benchmark http://micro-optimization.com/str_replace-vs-preg_replace-without-regular-expression.html

Answer (score 3):

Below is your pattern. using @solves your problem. and check it in sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b5eea90457a5f3d121452a20de4ac79895c916d)

```
 $string = "Welcome [firstname] [lastname]";

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '@\[firstname\]@';//this is what you need
$patterns[1] = '@\[lastname\]@';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'Marcello';
$replacements[1] = 'Silvestri';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with str_replace(). Did a small test, you can see the code below:

```
$string = "Welcome [firstname] [lastname]";
$patterns = array("Marcello", "Silvestri");
$replace = array("[firstname]", "[lastname]");

$result = str_replace($replace, $patterns , $string);

echo $result;
```

see also PHP [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)